# vue.js double v-for in list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I'm using vue.js in my project and I've got a question: how could I display elements of v-for inside of another v-for as list items or select options?
I have abstractly something like:

```
<div v-for='item in items'>
  <div v-for='element in item.elements'>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Would highly appreciate any possible help, thanks!

Comment: your abstract code is correct.What exactly does not work in your real code?

Comment: @LinusBorg it is correct, but I want to make select or list instead of divs, and I don't know how, because changing <div> tags to <ul> and <li> for example, will make several lists with one element in each

Comment: Well, it depends what your result should look like. Can you provide 1) the structure of `items` and 2) the desired endresult in HTML?

Comment: items is like an array with another array inside: `{"id":2,"user_id":"2","client_id":"2","agency_id":"0", "created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"deleted_at":null,"elements":[{"id":1,"title":"yay"}]`
And I want to have element titles listed as <li> in one <ul> tag

Comment: and how do you select the `item` from the `items` array? if you want to display all the elements from all the items, then you need a double `v-for`. If you want to display the elements from a specific item, then you must specify how do you select that item

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use a `<template>` tag so as not to render an extra div.

```
<ul>
 <template v-for='item in items'>
  <li v-for='element in item.elements'>
    {{element.title}}
  </li>
 </template>
</ul>
```

`<template>` tag is not supported in IE however.  A universal solution would be to make a computed variable that returns all of the titles:

```
computed:{
  titles:function(){
    var titles = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
      for(var k = 0; k < this.items[i].length; k++){
        titles.push(this.items[i][k].title);
      }
    }
    return titles;
  }
}
```

Then you can just do `v-for="title in titles"`